# How to store functions using SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, sqlitestudio

For example, I am creating one table to store a complex function such as y= α·β·(2|ΔP|/ρ)^0.5.by the way, I will call the function from this table through R Program. Thanks for your attention!

Comment: i'm not sure about R capabilities, but SQLite relies on hosting application to provide implementation of custom functions. SQLite has API to register implementation for your custom functions.